# Lookup value in dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, vlookup

I have a main dataframe and three smaller dataframes. Ultimately, I want to create a new column in the main dataframe that indicates whether each row meets two conditions.

1. The value in column A of the main dataframe appears in column BB of the any of the smaller dataframes.
2. For rows where the value of column A and column BB match, the difference between column B of the main dataframe and column of any of the smaller dataframes is less than five.

I've only included one of the smaller dataframes for simplicity's sake.

```
data = [['Tom', 10], ['Nick', 15], ['Juli', 14], ['Tom', 7], ['Juli', 9]]

main_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])

    A     B
0  Tom    10
1  Nick   15
2  Juli   14
3  Tom     7
4  Juli   9

data1 = [[5, 'Juli'], [17, 'Tom'], [6, 'Juli'], [8,'Tom']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['AA', 'BB'])

   AA   BB
0  5   Juli
1  17  Tom
2  6   Juli
3  8   Tom
```

I would like my final dataframe to look like this:

```
    A     B    C
0  Tom    10   X
1  Nick   15
2  Juli   14    
3  Tom    7    X
4  Juli   9    X
```

I've tried merging the dataframes, but it creates too many rows and exceeds python's limit.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with tolerance:

```
tmp = (pd.merge_asof(main_df.reset_index().sort_values(by='B'),
                     df1.rename(columns={'BB': 'A', 'AA': 'B'})
                        .sort_values(by='B').assign(C='X'),
                     on='B', by='A', tolerance=5, direction='nearest'
                     )
         .set_index('index')['C'].fillna('')
      )

main_df['C'] = tmp
```

Output:

```
      A   B  C
0   Tom  10  X
1  Nick  15   
2  Juli  14   
3   Tom   7  X
4  Juli   9  X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Tom', 10], ['Nick', 15], ['Juli', 14], ['Tom', 7], ['Juli', 9]]
main_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])

data1 = [[5, 'Juli'], [17, 'Tom'], [6, 'Juli'], [8,'Tom']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['AA', 'BB'])

main_df['C'] = main_df.apply(lambda row: 'X' if (row['A'] in df1['BB'].values) and any(abs(row['B'] - df1.loc[df1['BB'] == row['A']]['AA']) < 5) else '', axis=1)

print(main_df)
```

New column C will be  added in the main_df dataframe then apply method is used to apply a function to each row of the dataframe. The lambda function checks if the value in column A of the current row appears in column BB of the df1 dataframe and if the absolute difference between the value in column B of the current row and the value in column AA of the df1 dataframe is less than 5. If both conditions are met, it returns the string 'X'. Otherwise, it returns an empty string. The axis=1 parameter specifies that the function should be applied to each row of the dataframe. The resulting series is assigned to the C column of the main_df dataframe.